# Speed/Efficiency : Should I Parallelize This std::map Insert?

Tags: c++

I have a map, and vector of maps:

```
std::map <key, obj> baseValues;
std::vector< std::map<key, obj> > mapContainer;
```

I want to merge baseValues into each element of mapContainer, so something like:

```
for(std::map <key, obj>& aMap: mapContainer)
            aMap.insert(baseValues.begin(), baseValues.end());
```

My question is: should I parallelize this insertion, or will making this parallel just create more overhead and make things worse?

Comment: How about giving it a try?

Comment: STD Vector means something else if you know anything about epidemiology. I changed your title to `std::vector` instead ;)

Comment: This cannot be answered in a general fashion and is therefore off-topic. Just try it (e.g. with openMP this is fairly easy to do).

Comment: Which overload of `std::vector::insert` are you trying to use?  I don't see any that takes just two iterators.

Comment: Sorry! The problem is slightly different, I'm actually trying to do this with std::maps instead of std::vectors o_0

Comment: Measure if this operation is really a performace bottleneck before starting down that rathole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it! Your code is most likely *not* CPU bound because there are almost no calculations within the loop. If it takes too long (which I doubt), it is because you are allocating and initializing a lot of memory. Those allocations won't go away with parallelism, so your parallel code would definitely run slower.

### Update: CPU / IO bound

From wikipedia:

> In computer science, a computer is CPU bound (or compute bound) when the time for it to complete a task is determined principally by the speed of the central processor: processor utilization is high, perhaps at 100% usage for many seconds or minutes.
>
> In computer science, I/O bound refers to a condition in which the time it takes to complete a computation is determined principally by the period spent waiting for input/output operations to be completed. This is the opposite of a task being CPU bound.
>
> The I/O bound state is considered undesirable because it means that the CPU must stall its operation while waiting for data to be loaded or unloaded from main memory or secondary storage.

So yes it is the CPU that is "doing" the insertions, but "doing" an insertion requires very little actual computation (1%) and very much waiting for the RAM to catch up (99%). The insertion needs to be stored somewhere, right?

So throwing more CPUs at your problem doesn't help at all because the bottleneck is your RAM.

Comment: Sorry if this is naive, but can you elaborate on what you mean by CPU bound? What is doing the insertion work if not the CPU?

Answer (score 1):

The final answer depends on the number of elements in objVect: if it's small, than the overhead due to the creation of a thread may be higher that the sequential execution of an iteration. A good technique is to create a pool of threads, and a queue where your threads can look for jobs to complete. The final effect of my suggestion is to create just a limited number of threads at the beginning of execution, and then reuse them during iterations